# Grant permission to KILL connections (sessions) for certain databases only?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, kill

```
For a SQL Server on a VM/physical box (not Azure SQL database!)
```

Is this possible to grant KILL permission, but in a way that grantee can kill connections only for certain databases ?

I would not want to grant this user ability to kill any connection, but just 1 database

Thanks!!

Comment: Do end users ever run queries that references tables from multiple databases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Granting highly selective / fine-grained permission is rather easy via module signing:

1. `USE [master]`
2. Create a stored procedure to do whatever you want the low-privileged Login(s) to be able to do, with the necessary checks, etc.
3. Create a Certificate
4. Create a Login from that Certificate
5. Grant that Certificate-based Login the *minimum* level of permissions required to accomplish what the Stored Procedure is coded to do (in this case it might just be `ALTER ANY CONNECTION` (according to @sepupic)
6. Sign that Stored Procedure with that Certificate using `ADD SIGNATURE`
7. Grant the low-privileged Login(s) `EXECUTE` permission on that Stored Procedure.

HOWEVER, figuring out what Session / SPID is affecting which DB(s) is not easy. The `database_id` reported in `sys.dm_exec_sessions` is the "current" database: either what was connected to / their default DB if not specified in the connection string / whatever DB was changed to via the most recent `USE` statement. But the "current" database isn't necessarily where the problem is. Anyone can execute code and run queries in other DBs using 3-part names (a query can reference 3 tables, each in separate DBs, and none of them being in the "current" DB). So, I'm not sure how you would *reliably* enforce the "only certain DBs" constraint.

Answer (score 4):

No. It's not possible, at least just manipulating the permissions.

To be able to kill a session one should have `ALTER ANY CONNECTION` server level permission. There is nothing to do with database

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but you could use a stored procedure with execute AS permissions and then grant the user in question access to that procedure.  Here is something that should work to get you started.

This link https://sqlstudies.com/2014/02/26/impersonating-a-server-level-permissions/ goes into more detail about using EXECUTE AS in production code.  Needless to say, use this with caution and make sure you really need/want to do it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_KillConnection (@SessionID INT = NULL)
WITH EXECUTE AS 'domain\privilegeduser'
AS

DECLARE @KillCmd NVARCHAR(4000)

IF @SessionID IS NULL
BEGIN
    --Just return all sessions for the valid database.
    SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE DB_NAME(dbid) = 'DatabaseName';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Check to make sure the passed in session is attached to the valid database (no cheating!)
    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE @SessionID = spid AND DB_NAME(dbid) = 'DatabaseName')
    BEGIN
        --Show the information for that specific session.
        SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE @SessionID = spid AND DB_NAME(dbid) = 'DatabaseName'; 

        --Kill the session.
        SET @KillCmd = 'KILL ' + CAST(@SessionID AS NVARCHAR(5));
        EXEC sp_executesql @KillCmd;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --throw an error if they try and kill a session that is not in the database they have access to.
        ;THROW 50000, 'Requested Session ID is not attached to a valid database', 1;
    END
END
```

Comment: In this code 'domain\privilegeduser' is a user and not a login. To make it work you need to make your db **TRUSTWORTHY**. I think it should be mentioned in the answer, as it can open a secutirty hole on the server

Comment: @sepupic is correct that this permission is server-level, so `TRUSTWORTHY ON` is needed for the `domain\privilegeduser` User to link to its associated Login. And that `TRUSTWORTHY ON` is undesirable. Impersonation / `EXECUTE AS` is almost, if not entirely, never needed as module signing fixes almost everything, if not everything. Please see my [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185860/30859) for details. Also, I wouldn't use `sys.sysprocesses` as it's a compatibility view. Instead use some combination of  `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, `sys.dm_exec_requests`, and `sys.dm_exec_connections`.